# Citation of creative commons images with Office 2013

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013

Office 2013 (e.g., PowerPoint) allows us to `Insert` `Online Pictures` that we can find using `Bing Image Search`. By default, the images found using this are under Creative Commons licence. Excellent way to make sure we're re-using images ethically.

**Edit** Here's an image of what the insert process looks like. You can see that PowerPoint even shows the URL of the image you're about to insert (look below the yellow part stating it's creative commons):

[image]
<sub>(source: [addictivetips.com](https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Insert-Picture.png))</sub>

However, it seems that Microsoft only goes half way. When you insert the image, there is no record of where it came from. Wouldn't the best thing to do be something like make a hyperlink to the original image or a small caption below the image stating the license? I'm looking for a "trace" in the Image properties, but can't find it anywhere.

Is there a way to automate the citation of images found this way in Office 2013?

I'll point out that when you copy/paste text from the Kindle software, the "pasted" text contains the citation of the source (appended at the end).

> "Sometimes the top-down approach is so abstract that it's hard to get started."
> McConnell, Steve (2009-11-30). Code Complete (Kindle Locations 4538-4539). OReilly Media - A. Kindle Edition.

I'm dumbfounded as to why more programs don't do this in 2013...

Here's a tutorial on Youtube that shows how to cite an image properly (manually). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syt24LJvzlY

Comment: So add the information yourself. Any good author will make sure any copyright in their content is cited the correct way. Office can't know what this information is. **You have to understand not every Online Picture will have the same copyright license.**  **What Kindle software because I have never experienced that.**

Comment: Kindle 1.10 under Windows 7. See my edit for the sample.

Comment: Yahoo+Bing and Google provide advanced search features to find images that have a license allowing reuse. Google's you can find via Advanced Search options for the Image search, and Yahoo+Bing's is described here: http://www.ysearchblog.com/2013/01/10/image-search-flickr-photos/

Comment: Kindle is creating citation for a book its able to read the meta data for.  As I indicated Power Point can't always make this same assumption what the license is for the picture.  Best leave it to  the author of the Power Point presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Since PowerPoint doesn't expose the source of the picture or, so far as I know, give any way of capturing the url or other citation at the time the picture's inserted, I don't believe there's a clean way of automating this.  You can see the name of the site at the bottom of the dialog box as you click each image and in some cases (all?) follow the link to the picture.

Manually, though.

If you have the necessary info (url, author, whatever) and want to apply it to a picture, you could add it as part of the Alt Text (title or description) though that's not really the intended use of Alt text.

Or with an add-in or a bit of VBA you could add what are called "tags" to the image; these are not visible to the user w/o code.

Comment: PowerPoint *does* show the source of the picture when you find it. See my edit.

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear. And had my programmer's hat on.  By "expose", I meant "make available to the user or code" and should have said "after the picture's inserted".  As I mentioned, you can see source site in the dialog box at the time you select the image (but just the root URL, not the URL of the image itself, so it's not an entirely adequate citation, IMO).  In any case, other than noting the information shown in the insert d'log AT THE TIME OF INSERT, and applying it in one of the suggested ways, there's no feature available to help with this.  I totally agree that there SHOULD be.

Comment: Citations of images are supposed to have the context (root URL) according to http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rwit/resources/Citing-Images.pdf -- this is a "non programmer" kind of feature I'm looking for ;-)